# What's with the angry chef picture?

Tags: discussion

Someone using Mark Rage's account is editing whole questions and answers to just contain this picture:

[image]

There are many examples, [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/11263/4512) is just one, but others are easy to find.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mark has stepped down as a moderator.

The Soup Nazi reference comes from [this blog article](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php) discussing Stack Overflow (though many parts are still relevant to our site).

To summarize, Mark was unhappy with the direction of moderation (both community and elected moderator). He wanted a lighter touch from moderators, but things haven't been trending in that direction. He left [the following message](https://twitter.com/markrages/status/568158411151564801):

> Apologies to everyone who voted for me for moderator. I wasn't able to fulfill my promises.

While Mark has not been an active mod for a while, he will still be missed.

Comment: It's OK to disagree with the direction of the site. It's OK to advocate for something different. It's OK to leave if things don't end up going the way you like. It's NOT OK to throw a hissy fit and vadalize the place on the way out. It's REALLY REALLY NOT OK for a moderator to do that.  Now that he's shown his true character, no he won't be missed, at least not by all the people he just thumbed his nose at.  I now have a very different opinion of him after this childish stunt.  Good riddance.

Comment: To clarify (not to justify) he only edited his own posts.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that. If he had simply deleted some of his own answers, I might consider that childish but not vadalous. However, defacing posts, especially questions that had answers, is vadalism. There is a big difference between *"I'm leaving because I don't agree with the direction of this site"*, and *"I'm leaving, up yours!"* and then smashing a few dishes on the way out. I see now his account has been suspended. That's rather different from "stepped down" as moderator.

Comment: @OlinLathrop He suspended himself.

Comment: Wow, vandalism, its so heinous. It's like hitting roll back on a question is such arduous work... Grow up. Your childish reply is worse than his.

Comment: I didn't expect this from him. He sure will be missed. Him stepping down also means things will continue 'trending in that direction', even though he hasn't been active for a while. That's a pity, and perhaps a new election to fill that spot should be considered, to let the community decide in which direction we should continue. I know I have made the wrong choice in the last election.

Comment: Regardless of one's opinion about how the site is managed or how easy it is to restore the defaced posts, **vandalism is not cool**.

Comment: I know some of us have been in Mark's shoes... but after I had [my hissy fit](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4048/treatment-of-newcomers-enough-with-the-witty-demeaning-comments), the discussion that ensued made me conclude that we are just making a mountain out of an anthill. The differences of opinion are not that great (especially if you compare them to the world out there). Let's just let the natural forces balance out and shape up our community. Speak up when something bothers you and be done with it. Let's not take things too personally.

Comment: @Passerby: it's not hard to roll back an edit, but I'll echo Ricardo - **vandalism is not okay,** regardless of what the cleanup involves. Sorry to hear that Mark left. :(

Comment: @Passe: Actually, vandalism *is* a pretty heinous for a system like SE.  All we ultimately have is the content here.  It is realatively easy to clean up, but someone still has to find all the places it was done and roll back all the edits.  You really think it's fair for the volunteers here to have to do that?  Think of the chaos if even 1% of users did this.  And, this was done by a moderator.  We give moderators special powers, but in return hold them to a higher standard and expect them to act as responsible examples.  Mark has violated that trust and thumbed his nose at all of us.

Comment: It's a one off event, yet you all are acting like this is as bad as Hitler.

Comment: W5VO: I don't see why you deleted Tut's answer. It explains what the picture is, which I didn't know before since I never watched that TV show.  His answer was useful to me. Nothing Tut said warranted deletion as far as I can tell.

Comment: Meh, kinda sad. Something about the Stack format sucks for the topic of EE. Too many big egos and condescending attitudes competing for fake internet points, I guess.

Comment: I was wondering what prompted the deletion as well. After I learned the true story, I would have deleted my answer myself as I was only speculating; but I did wonder why it was deleted by a moderator. I certainly didn't mean anything offensive.

Comment: I'm not sure about him not being active anymore though. He has kept reviewing a lot, especially the close votes queue. His very tolerant input there will certainly be missed.

Comment: @Tut I deleted it because it was speculation after the time for speculation had passed. No other reason.

Comment: No problem. As I said, I would have deleted it myself. Thanks for the clarification.